# What do the class-specific numbers mean in this scatter plot matrix? (Made using the R function ggpairs)

Tags: r, scatterplot

I found some code online that uses the `ggpairs()` function from R
to draw a scatter plot matrix for the famous iris dataset.

```
library(GGally)
ggpairs(iris, columns = 1:4, aes(color = Species)) + 
    ggtitle("Anderson's Iris Data -- 3 species")
```

[image]

What do the class-specific (in this case species) numbers mean?
For example, in the Sepal.Width and Sepal.Length rectangle,
we have the numbers "setosa: 0.743" and "versicolor: 0.526".
I am aware that "Cor: -0.118" indicates the correlation between Sepal.Width and Sepal.Length.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 3 species in the iris dataset (under Species column). In your ggplot, you specified `color = Species`, this groups the observations by that the Species columns, gives you the different colours and also correlation within each species.

For example if we :

```
by(iris[,1:4],iris$Species,cor,method="spearman)
iris$Species: setosa
             Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width
Sepal.Length    1.0000000   0.7425467    0.2671758   0.2780984
Sepal.Width     0.7425467   1.0000000    0.1777000   0.2327520
Petal.Length    0.2671758   0.1777000    1.0000000   0.3316300
Petal.Width     0.2780984   0.2327520    0.3316300   1.0000000
------------------------------------------------------------ 
iris$Species: versicolor
             Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width
Sepal.Length    1.0000000   0.5259107    0.7540490   0.5464611
Sepal.Width     0.5259107   1.0000000    0.5605221   0.6639987
Petal.Length    0.7540490   0.5605221    1.0000000   0.7866681
Petal.Width     0.5464611   0.6639987    0.7866681   1.0000000
------------------------------------------------------------ 
iris$Species: virginica
             Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width
Sepal.Length    1.0000000   0.4572278    0.8642247   0.2811077
Sepal.Width     0.4572278   1.0000000    0.4010446   0.5377280
Petal.Length    0.8642247   0.4010446    1.0000000   0.3221082
Petal.Width     0.2811077   0.5377280    0.3221082   1.0000000
```

You can see for setosa, correlation between sepal.length and sepal.width is 0.743, for versicolor it is 0.526 and so on